# Unable to get my dropdown information to show correctly and in order from database in this format MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a form dropdown that pulls information directly from my table (boardDates) from my column (Board_Date). I set Board_Date as a varchar so that I could output each date as:

```
09/10/2021 
10/11/2020 
11/12/2019
```

The problem is that I cannot get it to display correctly in the dropdown like this based on the year:

```
11/12/2019
10/11/2020
09/10/2021
```

The closest I could come to is this line of code, but it displays the year in order, but not in the format I need it which is mm/dd/yyyy.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Board_Date,'%m/%d/%Y') as date_board FROM `boardDates` order by date_board ");
```

Any help is much appreciated...

Here is the main code:

```
<div class="form-group col">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="board_date">Anticipated Board Date</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="board_date" id="board_date">
                <?php
                    echo "<option disabled selected value>SELECT</option>";
                    while($rows = $resultSet7->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $color == $color1 ? $color = $color2 : $color = $color1;
                        $bdate = $rows['Board_Date'];
                        echo "<option value='$bdate' style='background:$color';>$bdate</option>";
                        
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: Have you tried `DATE_FORMAT("11/12/2019", "%m/%d/%Y");`?

Comment: _"I set Board_Date as a varchar"_ - Don't do that. If the column contains a date, store it as "date" in the format `Y-m-d` (how MySQL like it's dates) and use [date_format()](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/) to format the date the way you want it when you fetch the data, or even use PHP's `date()` on output instead. Keep the data in your database as accurate as possible. If you do that, you won't need to jump through as many hoops as you currently need to.

Comment: *I set Board_Date as a varchar* This is bad practice. Change the datatype to DATE back (if it is possible yet), and use DATE_FORMAT function while retrieving the date in the format which you need.

Comment: first of all if you are adding a date into the database, then it will be must to select the data type to DATE. Default format will be YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. And whenever you want to change the format then use ->  date("mm-dd-yyyy", strtotime($originalDate)); . This will be a correct method to use the date.

Comment: @ARVINDIT *Default format will be YYYY/MM/DD.* This is wrong for MySQL.

Comment: As mentioned, store dates using a proper date data type, or don't bother with an RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT Board_Date as date_board 
FROM `boardDates` 
order by STR_TO_DATE(Board_Date,'%m/%d/%Y');
```

After the comments:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Board_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Board_Date FROM boardDates")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The code:  `SELECT Board_Date as date_board FROM boardDates order by STR_TO_DATE(Board_Date,'%m/%d/%Y');` displays the dates in order by the year, such as 2020-10-11 and 2021-09-10  and not 10-11-2020 and 09-10-2021

Comment: I tried `$resultSet7 = $conn->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Board_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM boardDates);` But I keep getting a Syntax Error, unexpected T_String, expecting , or )

Comment: I was able to figure out the error, I was missing (") SO now I am using `$resultSet7 = $conn->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Board_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM boardDates");` but there are no dates showing up in my form??? I tried the SQL and it works fine, but my form is not displaying the dates now.

Comment: @Joe904 Could you show the code rendering the form as well?

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: Well, you need to set alias for the column. Could you try? Also, why you omit the 'order by'?

Comment: This did not work: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Board_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Board_Date, FROM boardDates");`

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Board_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Board_Date FROM boardDates")` try it like this